# Google Takeout from G Suite Download from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am a G Suite admin for a nonprofit, and just discovered the Data Export feature, which seems to be like an individual account's Takeout.

The export files were prepared, and are now available to download from a bucket in Google Cloud Platform Storage. However, there are many, many folders and trying to go in and out of each one to download the many, many .zip files in each sounds like a major headache to track.

I use Transmit on my Mac, and it has the ability to connect to Google Cloud Storage through the interoperability with Amazon S3. However, when I connect I see nothing (as I don't otherwise use Google Cloud Storage). I cannot find a way to connect to the particular bucket that our Takeout data is in. Suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## G Suite Customer Takeout: Bulk Download using Terminal

Building on repertor's great insight, here are exact steps I took (on a fedora system) to programatically download my gsuite takeout from the bucket:

### Install gsutil standalone

```
# wget https://storage.googleapis.com/pub/gsutil.tar.gz
# tar xvfz gsutil.tar.gz
# cd gsutil
```

### Connect gsutil to G suite account

To create a read-only token, use the command below: visit the browser to get an API token, then paste the API token back into the terminal. Later it asks for a "project-id", which can be any string apparently.

```
# ./gsutil config -r
```

### Actually download the backup

Go to [G Suite Customer Takeout](https://admin.google.com/ac/customertakeout), click on "Access Archive" and find the bucket id. In my case, this ID has the form  `takeout-export-123456abcdef-123456abcedf`

To download the entire bucket recursively with rsync:

```
# ./gsutil rsync -r gs://takeout-export-123456abcdef-123456abcedf /tmp/
```

Comment: The only thing I had to change for this to work for me was:
`./gsutil rsync -r gs://takeout-export-fffecde8-58f6-4faa-8cab-6a3e9dc28de7/ /d/takeout`

Comment: Does not work. If I don't enter in a project ID, the command fails with "CommandException: No default project ID entered. The default project ID is needed by the ls and mb commands; please try again."

Comment: Bummer, I got "Regular Gmail accounts cannot be used to sign in to admin.google.com."

Comment: Mid 2023, this now unfortunately fails with, *'CommandException: The user account authentication flow no longer works as of Febuary 1, 2023. Tokens generated before this date will continue to work. To authenticate with your user account, install gsutil via Cloud SDK and run "gcloud auth login"'*

Answer (score 2):

After speaking with support (who told me there's no other way of downloading files besides the browser; I informed them that this feature is therefore basically worthless) I kept digging.

The `gsutil` that Google offers holds the key! After installing it (just it, not the full SDK: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install), I was able to initialize it to be able to access my account, put in the gs:// address that the Bucket provided, and use `rsync` (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) to download it all. Otherwise I would have had to go in and out of 50 directories—and every .zip file was *NAMED IDENTICALLY* save for a '01' or '02' at the end. A nightmare for a routine activity.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer - a lifesaver! I flesh it out below with some more step-by-step instructions how to download a gsuite backup

Answer (score 1):

Trying this in February, 2022, I found the following works:

$ gcloud auth login

This command generates a URL to open in your browser.  After logging in there and granting permission, you get a verification code to paste back in your terminal.

$ gsutil -m rsync -r "gs://takeout-export-blah-blah-blah"

I ran the command in the previous answer, and it informed me that the download would run much faster with the "-m" argument.