# Can't download GSuite exported data using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-workspace, gsutil

I am trying to download the exported data from my GSuite (Google Workplace) account. I ran the data export tool and it is sitting in a bucket. I want to download all of the files but it says that the only way I can download multiple files is to use the `gsutil` utility.

I installed it using `pip instal -U gsutil`.

I tried running the following command:

```
gsutil cp -r \
  gs://takeout-export-3ba9a6a2-c080-430a-bece-6f830889cc83/20201202T070520Z/ \
  gs://takeout-export-3ba9a6a2-c080-430a-bece-6f830889cc83/Status\ Report.html \
  .
```

...but it failed with an error:

> ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.

I suppose that is because I am not authenticated. I tried going through the motions with `gsutil config`, but it is now asking me for a "Project ID", which I cannot find anywhere in the cloud storage web page showing the bucket with the exported files.

I tries following the top answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854587/google-takeout-from-g-suite-download-from-google-cloud-storage) question, but the project ID does not appear to be optional anymore.

How do I download my files?

Comment: Project ID is the unique ID of your google cloud project that you assigned at the time it was created.

Comment: I know what a project ID is. I never created a project, I was only given access to a bucket that was automatically created as a part of the data export process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project ID is "optional" in the sense that it's only used for certain scenarios, e.g. when you want to create a bucket (without explicitly specifying a project for it to live in), that project is specified as its parent. For most things, like your scenario of copying existing GCS objects to your local filesystem, your default project ID doesn't matter; you can just type whatever you want for the project ID in order to generate your boto file for authentication.

Comment: Thank you, I just put in random text and the configuration and download succeeded.