# Google Cloud Platform - Final exception: b'[Errno 28] No space left on device') for download of

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to download a backup from Google Cloud Platform.

[image]

And I get this error:

[image]

When I try this get space info, I get this:

[image]

And I need download around 250GB data.
What I have do?

Comment: CloudShell provides a 5 GB container. You cannot download 250 GB. Either use your desktop computer or launch a Compute Engine instance with at least a 250 GB disk.

Comment: And how can I do backup? Some manual for dummy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

As [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) commented:

> CloudShell provides a 5 GB container. You cannot download 250 GB. Either use your desktop computer or launch a Compute Engine instance with at least a 250 GB disk.

You can clearly see the size of the `/home` directory - it's 4,8GB.

Have a look at the [Cloud Shell documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell).

Make sure you have enough space at your machine's disk where you want to download your backup.

You can find more details about [downloading Google Takeout backups in this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784213/12257250).

> Go to [G Suite Customer Takeout](https://admin.google.com/ac/customertakeout), click on "Access Archive" and find the bucket id. In my case, this ID has the form  `takeout-export-123456abcdef-123456abcedf`

> Now to list the contents of the bucket, and download it recursively with rsync:

> ```
> # ./gsutil ls gs://takeout-export-123456abcdef-123456abcedf
> # ./gsutil rsync -r takeout-export-123456abcdef-123456abcedf /tmp
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the solution from the previous answer but what you indeed do have 5GB free as mentioned. Since the shell acts as a linux terminal, you can use the **ls** command to see all the files and folders in that directory. Then what you can do is delete all unwanted the files or folders that are usually stored in that directory when you are downloading items from the bucket, to release some space for the files you want to download. Using the command `rm -r {{folder name}}` you can delete folders and any contents recursively and using `rm {{file name}}` for you can delete files